# Newtonsoft.JSON error with text with HTML encoded character

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

I allow user input from TinyMCE on client and store it as a JSON string, then pass it to server ASP.NET C#.

The JSON String looks like this:

```
{ "mcfn2" : ";lt;p;gt;Trước đ& oacute;, việc tung ra t& ecirc;n miền lần đầu ti& ecirc;n được sự đồng & yacute; của ICANN - tổ chức quản l& yacute; t& ecirc;n miền quốc tế" }
```

(JSON string contains Vietnamese accent)

But when process on server, I received error "Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Line 1, position ...." (It looks like the error happened because of

```
đ& oacute;
```

). (In this page, I seperate & with character after it by a space, because it will automacally converted to a Vietnamese if there are no space)

There are no error if user input is English text (no Vietnamese accent).

Please guide me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

I know at this time this will probably not be useful for you, but maybe it can help another person.

You should convert your string to UTF8 to deal with accents (Vietnamese and many other languages) before serializing it to JSON. For that you can use this function:

```
private string ConvertToUtf8(string textOriginal)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textOriginal))
  {
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textOriginal);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
  }
  return string.Empty;
}
```